# Cluster before or after de-trend the data for time series data

Tags: time-series, clustering, trend, finance

I am working with a non-stationary time series finance data set. I would like to perform a clustering method on the data. My questions are, Do I need to de-trend the data first and then cluster it, or I can cluster the data first and then de-trend it? What is the best clustering method for finance data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you are looking for clusters in the original dataset or the "de-trend" one. You usually de-trend to apply some econometric technique, so I'd look for clusters in the original dataset and then apply the econometric model.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would like to cluster the original data then apply the econometric technique.

Comment: The chapter 4 of [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/) might give you some ideas.

Comment: Your help is really amazing. Thanks a lot.